# How to ssh from windows to linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, window, timeout

I want to ssh from windows 10 to linux. I installed OpenSSH server and client. When a I tried to ssh to my own pc, it work. Port 22 is opened. i tried without firewall. But when i tried to linux I get connection timed out.

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.xxx.x port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: I have two 2 pc. 1 windows, 1 linux. Linux PC can ssh to the third pc, but windows cant.

Comment: Ok, So why do you think, this is a "Linux"-problem, if the Linux-PC can access the Linux-server via SSH, but the WindowsPC can't? Can the WindowsPC ssh to other destinations?

Comment: There is not enough information to figure this out.  You probably have a network configuration problem between the computers.

Comment: Linux Firewall blocking incomming connections (often default of firewalls)? PS: you can use wireshark on the linux machine to see whats happening

Answer (score 0):

> I installed OpenSSH server and client

Where?

> Port 22 is opened

No it's not. At least not to the network path connecting the machines.

Start by pinging the server from the client. If that works (check the IP address) then name resolution, routing and connectivity are OK. Next check the output of `sudo netstat -nap | grep :22 | grep LISTEN` on the server. Check that it is listening on the address you are trying to connect to.

If that all checks out, look at the output of `iptables -L`

Comment: Hint: newer Windows 10 allow installation of Openssh delivered by microsoft. You do not need external components (any more). If only a client is needed, Putty is an option. Also enviroments lile msys2 also provide openssh (and a lot more!) --> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview